# Remove spacing between column and content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get an image to align to the very left of it's parent div box. However there seems to be some spacing issue that's preventing me from doing this.

Using float-left only gets me this far:

[image: Float-left]

It's a similar situation when attempting to float-right:

[image: Float-right]

```
    <section id="products-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class ="col-lg-1"> </div>
                    <div class ="col-lg-10 border-break-full"> 
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 border-red">
                                <img class="img-responsive float-right border-red" src="img/test-product.JPG" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class ="col-lg-1"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#no-gutters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/):

> Columns have horizontal padding to create the gutters between individual columns, however, you can remove the margin from rows and padding from columns with .no-gutters on the .row.

Try to use `.no-gutters` class like this:

```html
<section id="products-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-10 border-break-full">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-lg-4 border-red">
            <img
              class="img-responsive float-right border-red"
              src="img/test-product.JPG"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-8"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

*edit

Answer (score 0):

Use Flexbox:

```html
   

<div class="col-lg-4 border-red d-flex justify-content-start"> <img class="img-responsive float-right border-red" src="img/test-product.JPG" alt=""> </div>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```